# Как в listbox.DisplayMember Отображать 2 свойства обьекта

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Я студент первого курса, поэтому палками сильно не бейте:(

Вот суть проблемы:

Есть некий класс PacientClass :

```
public enum Vacitation
{
    Zero = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}
public string FullName { get; set; }
public Vacitation Vacitation { get; set;}
public PacientClass(string fullName, Vacitation vacitation)
{
    FullName = fullName;
    Vacitation = vacitation;
}
```

А также форма, где содержится listbox, в который я добавляю некоторые объекты класса PacientClass:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pacients = new List<PacientClass>
    {
        new PacientClass("Дарбинян Давид Арманович",Vacitation.Zero),
        new PacientClass("Красноборов Евгений Евгеньевич",Vacitation.Zero),
        new PacientClass("Бельтюков Александр Николаевич",Vacitation.Zero),
        new PacientClass("Рыбин Максим Андреевич",Vacitation.Zero),
        new PacientClass("Савченко Александр Алексеевич",Vacitation.Zero),
        new PacientClass("Павленко Артур",Vacitation.Zero),
        new PacientClass("Сурин Никита Константинович",Vacitation.Zero)
    };
    listBox1.DataSource = pacients;
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "FullName";
    
}
```

В коде видно что я делаю привязку и чтобы в самом listbox1 отображалось только поле Name, НО мне также нужно чтобы перед ФИО было int значение enum примерно как на картинке снизу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перерыл весь интернет ответа не нашёл, обязательное условие-использовать привязку, а не добавлять в listbox stringи.

Comment: Порывшись глубже нашёл интересное решение своего вопроса : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679253/how-to-append-two-field-values-in-combobox-display-member-in-c-sharp

Comment: Да, верно, нужно добавить дополнительное свойство.